# How to incorporate all changes I have made in one Git repo to another repo?

Tags: git, command-line, merge, gitlab, git-merge

I have two similar Git repositories.  One is hosted on GitHub, called
myrepo_github; and another one is hosted on GitLab; called
myrepo_gitlab. The two repositories are similar in the sense that
they are frequently merged in our company, and they have the same copy
for some corresponding commits.

Now I need to incorporate all changes I have made in myrepo_github to
myrepo_gitlab. What are the commands to do this task?

I do not need to transfer all histories of my commits, but only the
final changes I have made in all files that I have touched.  My
question may not be clear, but any inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Git is decentralized. While 99% of the time we are working on a remote called `origin` you can add multiple remotes and work on them. Add a separate remote with the url pointing to the second (remote) repository location and work on it normally by adding the remote name when referencing stuff.

```
git clone https://something/myrepo_gitlab dir
cd dir
# git remote -v  # origin points to myrepo_gitlab
git remote add myrepo_github https://something/myrepo_github
git fetch myrepo_github
git pull myrepo_github master  # or rebase or pull --rebase
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I incorporate *only* changes I have made? The one above seems to incorporate *all* changes into a new repo?

Comment: For example find the commits only you made and cherry pick them.

Comment: How can I use git fetch myrepo_github while cherry picking my own commits? I searched Google in vain.

Comment: `How can I use git fetch myrepo_github while cherry picking my own commits?` I do not understand, these are 2 separate operations. You cannot use git fetch at the same time as cherry picking, because one operation will lock `.git` directory, you can use one after another. You can specify revisions for cherry-pick as explained in `man gitrevisions`

Comment: Why not use GitLab's mirroring feature?